# Android + Cucumber = Test running failed

Tags: android, testing, cucumber

I just created a simple Android app and a basic Gherkin feature file.

Here is my `build.gralde`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.guddy.maxnumberapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'fr.guddy.maxnumberapplication.test.e2e.CucumberInstrumentation'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation group: 'com.android.support', name: 'design', version: '28.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '4.2.3'
    androidTestImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '4.2.3'
    androidTestImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-android', version: '4.2.2'
    androidTestImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '4.2.3'
}
```

I defined my feature in `app/src/androidTest/assets/features` and a class with the given/when/then steps.

I defined an instrumentation:

```java
package fr.guddy.maxnumberapplication.test.e2e;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "features"
)
public final class CucumberInstrumentation extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    private final CucumberInstrumentationCore instrumentationCore = new CucumberInstrumentationCore(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle arguments) {
        super.onCreate(arguments);
        instrumentationCore.create(arguments);
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        waitForIdleSync();
        instrumentationCore.start();
    }
}
```

And I have also a runner:

```java
package fr.guddy.maxnumberapplication.test.e2e;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = "fr.guddy.maxnumberapplication.e2e.steps",
        features = "features"
)
public class CucumberRunner {
}
```

And here is what I get when running either the run or the gralde `connectedCheck` task:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'fr.guddy.maxnumberapplication.test.e2e.CucumberRunner' fr.guddy.maxnumberapplication.test/fr.guddy.maxnumberapplication.test.e2e.CucumberInstrumentation
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
Empty test suite.
```

and :

```
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
```

Can you help figure out what's the problem and why it doesn't run my tests?
Maybe you can see where I'm wrong and what part of the configuration is duplicated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: I'm having a similar error with simple custom runner I made to use a custom Application on my tests.  It extends AndroidJUnitRunner, just like yours, but it's really simple and I don't override much.

Comment: Check my answer here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-android/issues/22#issuecomment-475363348. If you have to stick with support-v4 and cucumber 4.2.3 then your instrumentation has to inherit from MonitoringInstrumentation, AJUR is incompatible. Second thing is that you need to have only cucumber-android and picocontainer in dependencies, delete explicit cucumber-java and junit deps. Also you should have only one class with @CucumberOptions

Answer (score 0):

You must add the following:

`testApplicationId "fr.guddy.maxnumberapplication.test"`

inside `defaultConfig{}` under `build.gradle file`